# Avoiding accidental double htmlspecialchars encoding?

Tags: php, html, encoding

I'm currently tightening up security on my website and I'm trying to make sure every single value passed from PHP to HTML is encoded correctly.

Currently, assigning values to the template will encode it, however some parts of the website are old and do not use templates.

I changed the workings of the functions I use to output HTML to encode all the values. This worked great for covering all the old pages, however it now causes double encoding on template values.

I changed the encoding function I use to do:

```
$textToEncode = htmlspecialchars_decode($szText);
return htmlspecialchars($textToEncode, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1');
```

This has worked from what I can see. By decoding it first, it will always ensure it doesn't double encode and I can't think of any reason where decoding an unencoded string would cause problems. Is this an ok solution?

Comment: Unencoded string: `"Type &amp; to render a & character"`. Decoding that would cause problems.

Comment: @Quentin Lame D: If I put that it with the decoding on, I get `"Type & to render a & character"` and if I do it with it off I get `"Type &amp;amp; to render a &amp; character"` Looks like I'm in for the long haul.

Comment: "Currently, assigning values to the template will encode it" it sounds like you need to turn this off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're simply out of luck. You either know that a string is encoded or not. You cannot detect or guess. What if I mean to write "&amp;" and a string in your database contains that value? That's the *original, unencoded* string. But it *looks* encoded.

You need to keep track of where and when and why you encode strings, you cannot figure it out reliably after the fact.

If one of your users wrote this in your hypothetical forum:

> The HTML entity for "&" is "&amp;".

Then your decoding and encoding, or "intelligent non-double encoding" that @Robert suggests, would turn this into:

> The HTML entity for "&" is "&".

And all meaning of that post is lost.

Answer (score 14):

If you look at the manual, you'll see that what you're looking for is the last argument of the function - `$double_encode` = ***false***, which is *true* by default:

```
string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = 'UTF-8' [, bool $double_encode = true ]]]
```

Thus:

```
htmlspecialchars($textToEncode, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution for you is to use **double_encode** param in **htmlspecialchars**

From manual:

> When double_encode is turned off PHP will not encode existing html entities, the default is to convert everything.

Double_encode was added in PHP 5.2.3

```
htmlspecialchars ( $stringToEncode, $flags, $charsetEncoding , $double_encode);
```

Comment: I understand your point. But it is better to use double_encode than encoding twice encoded text. Parameter prevents encoding existing html entities. The case that someone puts string as you suggested is marginal

Comment: It's arguably rare that a non-programmer would ever write in HTML entities on purpose, but people write ungrammatical/incorrect special character-laden garbage on the Internet all day; don't be surprised if you get some random results &etc;-3LOL&j/k<3 :)